# How to tell how long user visits website in React single page app?

Tags: reactjs

I'd like to record a metric for the amount of time a user is on a page - due to company rules, I can't use Google Analytics or anything similar for grabbing the time.

We have something to record metrics, but right now, my issue is just how to properly get the value for the amount of time spent on the page.

I've considered using timeme.js but haven't been able to wire it in to our React component yet and I'm not sure if I can use it for our purposes.

I also considered a simplified approach like just getting the time the main / root component was loaded and getting the difference between that and the time that the component was unmounted:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    // set start time
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
     // get difference between start time and end time, record metric 
  }
```

But the problem is, a lot of our users don't close the window and may leave the window open overnight and then just refresh the page the next morning so I don't think comopnentWillUnmount will happen when I think it will happen?

Does anyone have tips for getting this metric?

Comment: Google Analytics uses a session timeout that is set on the property to handle when a lingering user should not be treated as on the site. I'm sure they do a bit more than just this under the hood, but maybe that information might help in someway.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure about the way you want to implement but i will list some of the things you might need to combine.

1. **LocalStorage** to save some data - px time when user entered.
2. **MouseMove event** - To track if the user has stopped the activity.
3. **Window.onblur** and **Window.onfocus** events to check if the user has
   switched tabs.